# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction

Tags: grails

I am developing an grails application(server) to track the mobile device which are in the Wi-Fi network. The users will send a request to the webservice which is running on grails applicion(server) along with Mobileid and Wi-Fi IP address.

In my grails application i am staring multiple external java threads, each thread will be pinging the Wi-Fi IP address of each mobile device(one thread per one device to track). If any device IP is not reachable then i will update mobile status as "Disconnected" in the database from the external thread. Here only i am facing the issue, if more than one device is in not reachable then multiple threads are going to update the status of each device in the same table using **domain.withTransaction** method while i am getting the following exception

**org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:596)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTransactionManager.super$3$doBegin(GrailsHibernateTransactionManager.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor492.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:127)**

My Code:

**Pinging device in thread**

```
try {
    final InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
    boolean status = inet.isReachable(5000);
    if (status) {
        pool.run(MobileDeviceTracker.deviceMap.get(mobileId));
    } else {
         // Calling service to update the status of device as disconnected
        getUserMobileService().deviceDisconnected(mobileId, ipAddress);
    }
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

**Updating Status in Database**

```
class DisconnectionService implements UserMobileServiceInt{
     static transactional = true


    def void deviceDisconnected(String mobileId, String wifiIp){
        try{
            def mobile = Mobile.findByMobileId(mobileId)
            def userMobile = UserMobile.findByMobileAndWifiIp(mobile, wifiIp)
            userMobile.withTransaction {tx ->               
                userMobile.action = Constants.MOBILE_STATUS_DISCONNECTED
                userMobile.alarmStatus = Constants.ALARM_STATUS_TURNED_ON
                userMobile.modifiedDate = new Date()
                userMobile.save(flush: true)
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

I am trying last 4 days but i am not able solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Move the reads into the transaction, otherwise they'll be in a disconnected session and not the one that the transaction creates. Also, it's best to call static methods on the class, not an instance (in both Groovy and Java):

```
void deviceDisconnected(String mobileId, String wifiIp){
   try {
      UserMobile.withTransaction { tx ->
         def mobile = Mobile.findByMobileId(mobileId)
         def userMobile = UserMobile.findByMobileAndWifiIp(mobile, wifiIp)
         userMobile.action = Constants.MOBILE_STATUS_DISCONNECTED
         userMobile.alarmStatus = Constants.ALARM_STATUS_TURNED_ON
         userMobile.modifiedDate = new Date()
         userMobile.save(flush: true)
      }
   }
   catch(e) {
      e.printStackTrace()
   }
}
```

Comment: @ Burt: Still i am getting same exception. Is it due to the same hibernate session used between more than one thread? If it is like that, Is there any way to increase the hibernate session creation in grails? I didnt configure anything for hibernate? Can u tell me the better configuration of hibernate in grails?

Comment: No, that's the whole problem - the Hibernate session isn't available in the new thread. But using `withTransaction` (even if you're not updating) is a quick fix since it creates and binds a new session and keeps the loaded instances attached for the duration. Could you try `grails clean` and run again?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith unless things have recently (2.0?) changed, both withNewSession and withTransaction will not bind or create a hibernate session on a newly created thread. This is why the Executor Plugin and before it the Background Thread plugin exist.

Comment: Nope, not true. `withTransaction` has always done this. I often suggest it as a workaround for stuff like this even if you're not updating the database since creating a tx is relatively lightweight. `withNewSession` is newer but probably better if it's available since it does bind a session but doesn't create a tx - see the impl in HibernatePluginSupport.groovy (for 1.3)

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I apologize, you are correct, I just created a test app demonstrating this. I have no idea why we used the kludgy bindSession code in the first place, other than possibly the behavior wasn't the same in earlier 1.2?,1.1? versions. The second I get back to work in the morning that code is being replaced with a simple `withTransaction`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the verbose binding code suggested by Tiggerizzy. It is better to use the built in withNewSession method on domain classes:

```
Mobile.withNewSession {
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: When i use the Domain.withNewSession i am getting the following exception: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not open Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.getNewSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:527)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.getSession(HibernateTemplate.java:454)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:393)

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyKanagaraj 's code sounds like it is running on a thread not created by Grails, so there will be no context to create one. Using either the verbose and not perfect code I suggested or the Executor Plugin are the best ways to achieve a hibernate session on a random thread.

Answer (score 0):

No need for me to spread mis-information and bad ways of doing things. Both the answers from Burt and Graeme will work. I just wrote a [quick test app to prove this](https://github.com/bendoerr/ThreadsInGrails).