# Grails Service throwing Exception "org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow ..."

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails service containing a method

```
@Transactional
def method(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass(param1: param1, param2: param2, param3: param3, param4: param4)
    obj.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
}
```

The method fails silently, even though I provided the "failOnError" parameter. This already took me some time to figure out, so I changed it to:

```
@Transactional
def method(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    try {
        SomeClass obj = new SomeClass(param1: param1, param2: param2, param3: param3, param4: param4)
        obj.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Now, finally, I get to see the error message which is: "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here". This is curious. I always believed "@Transactional" would provide me with a valid Hibernate session. So I am a little at my wits' end here. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `session.open()` before accessing a database and `close` by specifying explicitly as one solution. And also a good answer detail is [Here by Burt Beckwith.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487866/could-not-open-hibernate-session-for-transaction)

Please use his example if it helps .

```
void deviceDisconnected(String mobileId, String wifiIp){
   try {
      UserMobile.withTransaction { tx ->
         def mobile = Mobile.findByMobileId(mobileId)
         def userMobile = UserMobile.findByMobileAndWifiIp(mobile, wifiIp)
         userMobile.action = Constants.MOBILE_STATUS_DISCONNECTED
         userMobile.alarmStatus = Constants.ALARM_STATUS_TURNED_ON
         userMobile.modifiedDate = new Date()
         userMobile.save(flush: true)
      }
   }
   catch(e) {
      e.printStackTrace()
   }
}
```

Comment: That solves the problem. Thank you. But I wanted to really understand what is going on and did some further research. Turns out "@Transactional" is not equal "@Transactional". There is a Spring version and a Grails version (grails.transaction.Transactional) of the annotation and I used the Spring version instead of the Grails variant, which was the initial cause to my problem. Thanks for the help anyways.